# Sanity with React BlockContent displays only plain text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

Ok, so I am working on a blog for my portfolio website, and I just got it working until I realized that when I style the body of my blog posts in Sanity Studio, those styles do not transfer to the actual website. All I see in the website is plain text. This might be a dumb question, but I have no Idea what i'm doing wrong.

Here is my SinglePost.js file:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import client from "../../client";
import BlockContent from "@sanity/block-content-to-react";
import Header from "../Header";

export default function SinglePost() {
    const [singlePost, setSinglePost] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const { slug } = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        client
          .fetch(
            `*[slug.current == "${slug}"] {
            title,
            body,
            mainImage {
              asset -> {
                _id,
                url
              },
              alt
            }
          }`
          )
          .then((data) => setSinglePost(data[0]))
        setIsLoading(false)
    }, [slug])

    const serializers = {
        types: {
          code: (props) => (
            <pre data-language={props.node.language}>
              <code>{props.node.code}</code>
            </pre>
          ),
        },
      }

    return (
        <div className = "bg-gray-100 dark:bg-zinc-900">
            <Header />
            {isLoading ? ( <h1>Loading...</h1> ) : (
                <section className = "p-5 pb-20 lg:mx-28 md:mx-16 sm:mx-8">
                    <h1 className = "title mb-20">{singlePost.title}</h1>
                    <div className = "flex items-center justify-center">
                        {singlePost.mainImage && singlePost.mainImage.asset && (
                            <img src = {singlePost.mainImage.asset.url} alt = {singlePost.title} title = {singlePost.title} className = "rounded-xl shadow-xl dark:shadow-gray-100/10" />
                            )}
                    </div>
                    <p className = "paragraph mt-5 mb-5">By Brandon Pyle</p>
                    <div className="">
                        <BlockContent serializers={serializers} blocks={singlePost.body} projectId="2hp9gld0" dataset="production" />
                    </div>
                    <button>
                        <Link to = "/blog" className = "button">Read more articles</Link>
                    </button>
                </section>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my blockContent.js file:

```
/**
 * This is the schema definition for the rich text fields used for
 * for this blog studio. When you import it in schemas.js it can be
 * reused in other parts of the studio with:
 *  {
 *    name: 'someName',
 *    title: 'Some title',
 *    type: 'blockContent'
 *  }
 */
export default {
  title: 'Block Content',
  name: 'blockContent',
  type: 'array',
  of: [
    {
      title: 'Block',
      type: 'block',
      // Styles let you set what your user can mark up blocks with. These
      // correspond with HTML tags, but you can set any title or value
      // you want and decide how you want to deal with it where you want to
      // use your content.
      styles: [
        {title: 'Normal', value: 'normal'},
        {title: 'H1', value: 'h1'},
        {title: 'H2', value: 'h2'},
        {title: 'H3', value: 'h3'},
        {title: 'H4', value: 'h4'},
        {title: 'Quote', value: 'blockquote'},
      ],
      lists: [{title: 'Bullet', value: 'bullet'}],
      // Marks let you mark up inline text in the block editor.
      marks: {
        // Decorators usually describe a single property – e.g. a typographic
        // preference or highlighting by editors.
        decorators: [
          {title: 'Strong', value: 'strong'},
          {title: 'Emphasis', value: 'em'},
          {title: 'Code', value: 'code'},
          {title: 'Highlight', value: 'highlight'},
        ],
        // Annotations can be any object structure – e.g. a link or a footnote.
        annotations: [
          {
            title: 'URL',
            name: 'link',
            type: 'object',
            fields: [
              {
                title: 'URL',
                name: 'href',
                type: 'url',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    // You can add additional types here. Note that you can't use
    // primitive types such as 'string' and 'number' in the same array
    // as a block type.
    {
      type: 'image',
      options: {hotspot: true},
    },
  ],
}
```

You can find the complete source code here: https://github.com/bpyle02/portfolio
If you would like to see a live example of the error, check out this blog post I made that is meant to have different headings, bullet lists, etc.: https://brandonpyle.netlify.app/blog/how-to-properly-write-a-github-readme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out what caused the problem. Because I am using TailwindCSS in this project, I have to install the Tailwind Typography plugin to get the styles working correctly for the block content.

To install this plugin, type `npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography` in the console and then add `require('@tailwindcss/typography'),` to the plugins section of the tailwind.config.js file.

Then add the 'prose' class to a div surrounding your BlockContent tag like so:

```
<div className="prose">
    <BlockContent blocks = {singlePost.body} />
</div>
```

If you need more help, check out this tutorial in the Tailwind Docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin